# Simple CArray questions

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

1.) What is the difference between

```
CArray <SomeClass> collection;
```

and

```
CArray <SomeClass,SomeClass> collection;
```

or even

```
CArray <SomeClass* ,SomeClass* > collection;
```

?

2.) While reading some comments on Stackoverflow I came to a note saying "Don't use CArray". Why should CArray not be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
CArray <SomeClass> collection;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
CArray <SomeClass, const SomeClass&> collection;
```

The second template parameter is used to specify the type through which members are accessed.  The template parameters [are described in the documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4h2f09ct(v=VS.100).aspx).

This:

```
CArray <SomeClass* ,SomeClass* > collection;
```

stores a collection of pointers to objects of type `SomeClass`, whereas the other two store collections of objects of type `SomeClass`.

As for why you "shouldn't use it," `std::vector`, which is part of the C++ language standard, and thus portable, is probably a better choice for most projects.  If you have legacy code that uses `CArray`, then you may need to use it, and there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is what is stored in the `CArray` object and how it is stored in the object, whether the `CArray` elements are objects or pointers to objects of some class.

`CArray` seems to have a few unexpected behaviors. It has been around for a long time and was designed to fit into the MFC ecosystem. The C++ Standard Template Library `vector` has much nicer and more generic characteristics especially when dealing with objects other than simple data types.

My experience has been with using `CList` and `CArray` with pointers to objects.  Doing this they seem to be more predictable though you do need to worry about managing memory.

One issue from looking at the source in `afxtempl.h` is that when the `CArray` is made larger through the internal function `SetSize()`, a `memcpy_s()` function is used to copy `CArray` elements from one memory area to another. So you need to be careful about pointers and shallow copying of `CArray` elements.  And since `memcpy_s()` is used rather than `memmove_s()` if you are doing something funky with over lapped memory areas, there may be an issue.

This may be why my experience with `CArray` as a container for pointers to objects seems to work much better.

The interesting thing is it looks like the `Append()` and `Copy()` methods use an internal function `CopyElements()` which performs an element by element assignment and not a `memcpy_s()` function call.  However these methods are used with `CArray` objects and not with the individual elements.

`CArray` is derived from `CObject` which means that the data structure will have all the baggage of `CObject`. However there are also some good things that `CObject` brings along in the MFC world like serialization.

It looks like you should use a reference as the second template argument so you should use `CArray <SomeClass, SomeClass &> collection;` if you are using a class.  I ran into problems when I did not do this until I discovered the section *Creating an Array List* from [MFC Collections: The CArray Class](http://functionx.com/visualc/collections/carray.htm).

Answer (score -2):

2) Since CArray reallocates memory when new element is added.